# SSL verification for pod

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-web-app-service

I have a service connection configured in Azure Web App (Windows Azure Web App) using certificate validation with a client. Below is also an example of a section with a code:

```
"ServerCertificateFileName": "test.pfx",
"ServerCertificatePassword": "111",
"AllowedCertificateTypes": "All",
"RevocationMode": "NoCheck",
"ValidateCertificateUse": "false",
"ValidateValidityPeriod": "true",
"Enabled": "false",
"Thumbprints": []
```

But when I decided to move the service to Linux for Kubernetes, it stopped working, I still went through validation and got 403 all the time. Tried and Windows image is all the same. Maybe I'm missing something. Please help me.

Comment: There's no service called "Linux for Kubernetes". Do you mean Azure Kubernetes Service?

Comment: Yes, Azure Kubernetes Service, and configure use Linux and Windows image for containers

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question? How did you migrate your service to AKS, how did you set up SSL for it? You provided information only about Azure Web App, but what about AKS? "it stopped working," - it's for your service in Azure Web App or in AKS already?